# PowerDesigner to Doctrine

Tags: database, doctrine, data-modeling, database-design, powerdesigner

I would like to know if is it possible to generate classes,xml or yaml using powerdesigner for doctrine? or is there any other database modeling software which allow me generate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [online free code generation service](http://modeling-languages.com/uml2php-full-code-generation-php-applications/) generates doctrine yaml files from simple UML class diagrams

Answer (score 0):

[ORM Designer](http://www.orm-designer.com/) will allow you to both design and continuously edit the visual model and then generate Yaml schema from it.

You can also import your existing Yaml files so you don't have to start from scratch.